# Error building serial_port Dart library on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, serial-port, dart

I'm trying to build serial_port Dart library ( https://github.com/nfrancois/serial_port ) on Mac OSX and Dart  1.9.0-dev.8.0.
After running

```
bin/serial_port.dart compile
```

the output is:

```
 Building project "/Users/joaobiriba/Documents/Projects/dartworks/serial_port/lib/src/serial_port.yaml"
    clang: error: no input files

    clang: error: no input files

    Building complete with some errors
```

Is it some env configuration problem?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a error from your gcc. Could you try this command line ? 
`xcode-select --install` ? It allows to install xcode command line tools.

Comment: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: I've built a libserial_port.dylib manually, where do I have to put this library to test the dart sample?

Comment: You have to put your libserial_port.dylib in `lib/src`.

Comment: Ok, using the manually builded library is working in serial_port. Where do I have to put in firmata package to use its examples?

Comment: When you use firmata, after `pub get`, you have to put in your `packages/serial_port/src/`. Because of symbolic link, this directory should correspond to `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serial_port-0.2.2+1/lib/src`

Comment: I still having no response by dart firmata samples using an Arduino Leonardo and the hand builded library on OSX, the scripts are idle waiting the Arduino connection.

Comment: I realize that I didn't mention that Firmata installation is need on Arduino. `Arduino IDE -> [File] -> [Examples] -> [Firmata] -> [StandardFirmata]`. If you have installed it yet, what is the version ?